# How to get data from a Django JsonField?

Tags: django, json

I would like to know how I can get ("decode?") the data from a JsonField, I'm having this:

```
{"pleople": "name=Jhon&email=email@domain.com", "id": 251304}
```

How I can pass this to my view like `name['Jhon']` or any kind of object to use with querySet or parameter?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? In `django-jsonfield` if you have a model with `some_field = JsonField()` you can put or retrieve a dict or list directly in `object.some_field`, all to/from JSON conversions are made automatically.

Comment: im sorry, that was a dictionary, i access it in this way key['value']

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs, parse_qsl

>>> parse_qs("name=Jhon&email=email@domain.com")
{'email': ['email@domain.com'], 'name': ['Jhon']} # allow multiple values

>>> dict(parse_qsl("name=Jhon&email=email@domain.com"))
{'email': 'email@domain.com', 'name': 'Jhon'} # dict w/ single value
```

Or you could use `django.http.QueryDict` directly

```
>>> from django.http import QueryQict
>>> QueryDict("name=Jhon&email=email@domain.com")
<QueryDict: {u'name': [u'Jhon'], u'email': [u'email@domain.com']}>
```